# Latest Pi3B+ board I2S mic and amp does not work

Tags: pi-3b+, i2s

I have tried installing AdaFruit I2S
[Speaker](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp/raspberry-pi-usage) and [Mic](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-test) on some newly bought `Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.4`

The install is not working anymore:

- The Speaker say it is installed but the sndrpii2scard does not appear after reboot (`play -L`)
- The Mic python install script says: Unsupported Pi board detected.

I have successfully installed and run with this scripts in old raspberry PI 3B+ purchased in 2020. (I have more than 50 working in the field)
These were `Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3`

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the correct device tree overlay is enabled for the I2S interface. You can do this by editing the /boot/config.txt file:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Make sure the following lines are present and uncommented:

```
dtoverlay=i2s-mmap
dtoverlay=rpi-simplecard
```

Comment: Yes. They are, this was an older image that already had this installed and working. However updating the older image was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. This was an older image (for 1.3 rev) that I have upgraded to latest boot and Linux.
However when I tried the install sequence:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo pip3 install --upgrade adafruit-python-shell
```

did not update the adafruit correctly.

Solution was to run this command too:

`sudo pip3 install --upgrade Adafruit-PlatformDetect`

After this the adafruit was correctly upgraded and new rev1.4 platform was detected and the Speaker and Mic install scripts worked fine.

`adafruit-python-shell` has a dependency on Adafruit-PlatformDetect.
However `pipdeptree` output show `adafruit-python-shell` requires any `Adafruit-PlatformDetect` installed, so if it was installed a long time ago (when rev1.4 did not exist), you need to update it manually.

```
adafruit-python-shell==1.8.0
  - Adafruit-PlatformDetect [required: Any, installed: 3.62.0]
  - clint [required: Any, installed: 0.5.1]
    - args [required: Any, installed: 0.1.0]
```